# Bash whiptail dies when changing directory

Tags: linux, bash, whiptail

I'm trying to change to a directory and run additional commands within my `whiptail` dialog screen, but after cloning my git repository it seems that my script is now dying when trying to change to the directory:

```
STATUS=0
touch log.txt
while [ $STATUS -lt "100" ]; do
  echo "cloning Repo" >> log.txt
  git clone git@git.bitbucket.org:abc/repo.git /repo >> log.txt 2>&1
  echo "changing directory" >> log.txt
  cd /repo >> log.txt 2>&1
  echo `pwd`
  echo "installing bundler" >> log.txt
  gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc >> log.txt 2>&1
  (( STATUS += 99 ))
  echo $STATUS
done | whiptail --gauge "Setting Up Neo (THIS WILL TAKE SOME TIME)..." 40 78 0
;;
```

Logging commands with `set -x`, this looks like:

```
:66+STATUS=0
:67+touch log.txt
:149+whiptail --gauge 'Setting Up (THIS WILL TAKE SOME TIME)...' 40 78 0
:68+'[' 0 -lt 100 ']'
:71+echo 'apt-get update'
:73+((  STATUS += 15  ))
:74+echo 15
:77+echo 'apt-get upgrade'
:79+((  STATUS += 15  ))
:80+echo 30
:83+echo 'apt-get -y git-all'
:85+((  STATUS += 15  ))
:86+echo 45
:111+((  STATUS += 30  ))
:112+echo 75
:115+rm -rf /repo
:116+echo 'cloning Repo'
:117+git clone git@git.bitbucket.org:abcd/repo.git /repo
:118+echo 'changing directory'
:119+cd /repo
::120+pwd
:120+echo /repo
:121+echo 'installing bundler'
:122+gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
:148+echo 100
:68+'[' 100 -lt 100 ']'
:5+true
::11+whiptail --title 'Configuration Menu' --menu 'Choose an option' 40 78 30 1 'Show current configuration.' 2 'Setup Wizard.' 0 Exit
```

The output of `log.txt` stops at `changing directory` and my whiptail menu goes back to the main page (as if the setup is done, but it's not since I should also see the `pwd` and `installing bundler` in the log too):

```
 cloning Repo
 Cloning into '/repo'...
 changing directory
```

I'm not getting any errors so diagnosing what's going on is posing to be the problem for me.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of bash? Assuming it's 4.x, you can log in detail to a non-default file descriptor

Comment: also, earlier in the script, did you run `set -e` (or set an ERR trap)?

Comment: ...so, before doing any of this: `exec {tracefd}>trace.log; BASH_XTRACEFD=$tracefd; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x`, and then bundle in `trace.log`; that'll log the commands run, each preceded by its line number.

Comment: No, no error trap.  Using 4.3.11(1)

Comment: Put that at the beginning of my script?

Comment: (Edited my above code, it was slightly wrong above)... and yes, at the beginning.

Comment: BTW, putting `>> log.txt` into your script over and over is inefficient -- it's re-opening the output file every time you do that! Consider putting something like `exec 3>log.txt` (or `3>>log.txt`, depending on whether you want to truncate on a new run) once at the top, then using `>&3` on every line you want to redirect there. (Can also use `exec {log_fd}>log.txt` and `>&$log_fd` if you want to use bash 4.1+'s new auto-FD-allocation support).

Comment: is it possible that some unexpected command consumes the output of `whiptail` ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edited the above with the trace.log output.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, we're piping *into* `whiptail`, not *from* it.

Comment: @Godzilla74, ...that log clearly shows that we're continuing after the `cd` command -- which is to say, it doesn't reflect that there actually *is* any kind of a problem at all.

Comment: @Godzilla74, ...can you create a MCVE -- that is, a minimal reproducer that folks who don't want to run a `gem install` on their machine or such can still use to reproduce the problem itself, and that you've *tested* to create the problem when running standalone? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for hints.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right... it just occurred to me that since I'm changing directories it has no where to right to since `log.txt` is in the previous directory.  Man, long day...

Comment: @Godzilla74, ...this is another problem that the advice I gave (of opening `log.txt` only once at the top of your script, and reusing that file descriptor) would have solved. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good call... time to revamp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `>>log.txt` on each command, that log file is being re-opened for every command -- meaning that using `cd` changes the directory in which that logfile is being created.

To fix this, **at the top of your script**, use:

```
exec 3>log.txt
```

...and, whenever you want to write to that file, append `>&3` to each command to write to that previously-opened file descriptor.

Comment: This works great, however the only issue I'm encountering is that >&3 redirects the output to screen as well, which overflows the `whiptail` gauge with text instead of the percentages.  Originally I was using `>> log.txt 2>&1` which suppressed the output to `log.txt`.

Comment: `>&3` does not in fact redirect output to the screen. Maybe you're referring to *stderr* going to the screen? To avoid that you'd want either `>&3 2>&1` or `>&3 2>&3`

Comment: Ok, so, I liked your auto-fd allocation method... `exec {log_fd}>log.txt` which I placed at the beginning.  Now, I have the following for a command `gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc >&$log_fd`.  Do I need to adjust the `exec...` at the top to something like: `exec {log_fd}>&3 2>&1>log.txt` or is that way wrong?  Sorry... the FD method is foreign to me!

Comment: `>&$log_fd 2>&1` will do at the point of usage (the `gem install bundler` command). The first redirection makes FD 1 point to `log_fd`, the second makes FD 2 a copy of FD 1.